# How Call function and include page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I defined for my page that when some user clicks on my image, It passes some page's relative-url to a function called selectImage():

```
<figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right">
<img src="assets/img/1/1.jpg">
<figcaption class="w3-spec-figcaption" style="background-image: url('assets/img/1/1a.jpg')"></figcaption>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="selectImage('lists/1.html')"></a>
</figure>
```

And I wrote this piece of code in my script tag:

```
var app = angular.module('projects', []);
    app.controller('projects_controller', function($scope) {
       $scope.selectImage = function(id) {
          $scope.includehtml = id;
       },
       $scope.remove = function() {
          document.getElementById('img_controllers').style.display = 'none';
       };
    });
```

And finally I defined that when user clicks on the image, Page includes the file with url that image passed to the function:

```
<div data-ng-include="{{includehtml}}"></div>
```

But It doesn't works :( Please help me It's very important to me...
**Note:** The page's using AngularJS 1.5.7.

Comment: instead of the div. Try using it as:
`<ng-include src="{{includehtml}}'"></ng-include>`

Answer (score 1):

Call your function in HTML like:-

```
<div data-ng-include="selectImage(id).includehtml"></div>
```

There is no need to write `{{ }}` expression while including template,
and you mentioned that templateUrl path in a function so use function name and then template name.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! The problem solved!

```
<div data-ng-include src="includehtml"></div>
```

Thanks @Saurabh Tiwari !

Comment: Glad I could help...!!

Answer (score 0):

Include page

```
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-include="'myFile.htm'"></div>

</body>
```

call function example

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <div ng-include="'myTable.htm'"></div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be used like,

```
<div ng-include=includehtml></div>
```

OR

```
<div data-ng-include=includehtml></div>
```

Please verify.